# WIndows Form Application with bluetooth communication

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

In a normal Windows Forms Application for laptops (**not** a Windows store application)  I need to communicate with a Bluetooth device.

For communicating with Bluetooth I need Windows' Bluetooth libraries:
[see this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.aspx)

Can anyone tell me how to add this reference into a normal application ?
My impression is that Microsoft has totally forgotten that normal applications need to communicate with Bluetooth as well sometimes .
Or am I overlooking something ?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) from [this question](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/786743/How-Can-I-Use-Windows-Devices-Bluetooth-Namespace) could help.